# VBA "Compile error: argument not optional"

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I have a VBA macro which selects the user's data type choice for other calculations.

```
Sub Function1()
'   Give the user macro options based on how fast or slow the computer is using advanced conditional compliling
MsgBox ("This macro by default treats all numbers as decimals for maximum precision. If you are running this macro on an old computer, you may want to relare numbers as singles, to speed up the macro.")
MsgBox ("Decimals are reccomended for any scientific conclusions.")
MsgBox ("Decimal: reccomended for maximum precision. Also slower." & vbNewLine & "Double: not reccomended." & vbNewLine & "Single: not reccomended. A lightweight double." & vbNewLine & "Long: rounds to nearest number. Massive range of possible values." & vbNewLine & "Integer: designed for quick estimates of data.")
vuserChoice = InputBox("Select a data type:" & vbNewLine & "1. Decimal" & vbNewLine & "2. Long" & vbNewLine & "3. Single" & vbNewLine & "5. Integer")

Select Case IsNumeric(vuserChoice)
    Case IsNumeric = True
       MsgBox ("A number cannot be entered for data type.")
    Case IsNumeric = False
         struserChoice = CStr(vuserChoice)

If struserChoice = "Decimal" Or "decimal" Or "1" Or "one" Or "on" Or "Dec" Or "dec" Then
    Call FunctionDecimal
ElseIf struserChoice = "Double" Or "double" Or "2" Or "two" Or "to" Then
    FunctionDouble
ElseIf struserChoice = "Single" Or "single" Or "3" Or "three" Or "three" Or "thee" Then
    FunctionSingle
ElseIf struserChoice = "Long" Or "long" Or "4" Or "four" Or "for" Or "foor" Then
    FunctionLong
ElseIf struserChoice = "Integer" Or "integer" Or "int" Then
    FunctionInteger
Else
    FunctionNotValidVarType
End If
'   MEeff = measure of efflux due to crudely purified HDL in scintillation
MsgBox "For additional information about this macro:" & vbNewLine & "1. Go to tab Developer" & vbNewLine & "2. Select Visual Basic or Macro." & vbNewLine & "See the comments or MsgBoxes (message boxes)."
End Sub
```

Here is the offending line of code:

```
    Case IsNumeric = True
```

What do I need to do to fix this? I know IsNumeric is a built-in VBA feature.

Comment: In any event -- why use a case statement (as opposed to an if-then-else) when deciding between 2 possibilities?

Comment: @JohnColeman it's in the code.

Comment: I can see that it is in the code, but the question is why. It isn't an idiomatic use of the case construct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The case labels should be values, not function names. Try

```
Case True
```